# sudo must be setuid root error and recovery mode requires root passwd?

Tags: ubuntu, sudo, ubuntu-10.10

When I try to execute `sudo su`, I receive the following message:

```
sudo: must be setuid root
```

When I try to reboot in recovery mode, it asks:

```
Enter root password for maintenance
```

I'm using Ubuntu 10.10. I can't do any tricks as mentioned in all other websites until and unless I get `sudo` working. How can I do that?

Comment: This isn't really a pogramming question.

Comment: you don't have the root password?

Comment: @Chris2048, Ubuntu systems generally do not have root passwords, as root logins are completely disabled. The `sudo` command is used to obtain root priviledges, and requires the executing user's password instead.

Answer (score 5):

Somehow your `sudo` executable lost its right permissions. Start to maintenance mode (`Ctrl+D`), it should not ask you for a password, if there is none set, and run the following command:

```
chmod 4755 /usr/bin/sudo
```

If you can not enter maintenance mode, you can boot from a Live CD/USB stick and mount the according filesystem and then run the `chmod` command.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the other way: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LostPassword

> If the "Standard Way" does not work for you and you recieve the "Give root password for maintenance" message, you can recover your password using the following steps
>
> 1. Reboot your computer
> 2. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> or <kbd>Esc</kbd> at the grub prompt (as earlier).
> 3. Select your image.
> 4. Highlight the line that begins kernel and press <kbd>e</kbd> to edit
> 5. Go to the very end of the line, change the `ro` to `rw` and add `init=/bin/bash`
>
> Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, then press <kbd>b</kbd> to boot your system.
>
> Your system will boot up to a passwordless root shell.
>
> 6. Type in `passwd username`
> 7. Set your password.
> 8. Type in `reboot`